# Motivo de fechamento personalizado não é mostrado na fila de análises

Tags: bug, status-pronto, fechamento

Ao se escolher um motivo personalizado para fechamento de uma pergunta, ele não é mostrado no cabeçalho do item a ser analisado. Acredito que o correto seria mostrar o texto personalizado pelo usuário que escolheu a opção "Outros", pois do jeito que está é necessário clicar em "Fechar" para então descobrir qual foi o motivo que votaram para fechar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]